# Add class into table row using php while loop which match both tables (mysql) id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've a `userkeywords` table and it's look like this :

```
ukid    cdid    kid
14      28      57
15      28      56
16      28      55
17      28      48
18      28      28
19      19      57
20      25      56
21      25      57
```

Now I'm getting which `cdid` have number of  `kid` with following query :

```
$query2 =  mysql_query("SELECT kid FROM userkeywords WHERE cdid = '$cdid'");
$result2 =  mysql_fetch_array($query2);
$eKid = $result2['kid'] . "<br/>";
```

and I'm getting this `$cdid` from a url :

```
http://localhost/contact-management/users/keywords.php?cdid=28
```

Now I'm getting all keywords from `keywords` table with following code and I want to add a class which match the `keywords` table `kid` with `userkeywords` table `kid`.

```
<?php
echo "<div id='keywordBox'>";
echo '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1055">';
$count = 0;
while($result =  mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  if($count%6==0 && $count!=0){    
    echo '</tr><tr>';
  }elseif($count==0) echo '<tr>';

    $kid = $result['kid'];
    $keywordName = ucfirst($result['keywordName']);     

    $keyword_short_name = ucfirst($result['keyword_short_name']); 
    $keyword_full_name = ucfirst($result['keyword_full_name']); 

    if($eKid === $kid){
        $class = "keywordHigligh";  
    }

    echo "<input type='hidden' id='kid' value='$kid'/>";    
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='cdid' value='$cdid'/>";  
    echo "<td width='400' onclick='keywordclick($kid,$cdid)' class='$class'><strong>$keyword_full_name</strong><strong> ($keyword_short_name)</strong><br/>$keywordName</td>";
    $count++;  
    }   
echo '</table>';
echo "</div";
?>
```

Now I'm confused where I need to place `$query2`  or How can I add a class to table row which match both mysql table `kid` ?

Comment: Try to remove one extra `=` in if condition, i think this will solve your problem. `if($eKid == $kid){ $class = "keywordHigligh"; }`

Comment: Let me try it but where i place $query2 ?

Comment: I tried it but not solved.

Comment: $query2 should be above while loop

Comment: If I use $query2 above while loop then I can get only one `kid` but user may have few `kid`.